# CSS class name shown in red in Firebug

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

Firebug's Style Panel shows some CSS class names in red.  Following is an example:

[image: CSS in red]

This class is defined and working.  What is the reason behind the color red?

I am on Win 7, FF 10.0.2, Firebug 1.10.0a5.

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is red? (for the colorblind..)

Comment: @PéterVarga, It's the `ul.tabs`

Comment: In "Inherited from <whatever>", tags are blue, IDs are navy blue, classes are red. It doesn't mean anything, it's just to make it easier to see the difference.

Comment: Im going to second what thirtydot posted, you might be overthinking this one too much.

Comment: @thirtydot: I think that qualifies as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In "Inherited from <whatever>", tags are blue, IDs are navy blue,
>   classes are red. It doesn't mean anything, it's just to make it easier
>   to see the difference.

As evidence to back up my comment above, here's the relevant section of Firebug's source code:

http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.9/skin/classic/console.css?r=12753#442

```css
.selectorTag {
    color: #0000FF;
}

.selectorId {
    color: DarkBlue;
}

.selectorClass {
    color: red;
}

.selectorHidden > .selectorTag {
    color: #5F82D9;
}

.selectorHidden > .selectorId {
    color: #888888;
}

.selectorHidden > .selectorClass {
    color: #D86060;
}

.selectorValue {
    font-family: Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #555555;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  You are right, I was overthinking! ;-) CSS is so convoluted though.  I cannot think of trying to learn CSS without Firebug.